# Why does my output ignore my string and prints out "hello world /n$"?

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently taking the Harvard CS50 course through edX and I just started the mdule on C. I wrote the code as it appears on the slides but I think I did something wrong. i attached a screenshot. Please keep in mind that I'm not using vs code as it is on the application but a cloud based version provided by the course.

what I wrote:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    string answer = get_string("What's your name? ");
    printf("hello %s\n ",answer);

}
```

what the output is

hello world/n$

I would also like to know why the /n$ appears at the end for me, when it didn't for the instructor.

Comment: What are you typing at the prompt? Are you certain you have recompiled your program after any edits to the source code? The `$` at the end is likely the shell prompt but there's no space before it as there is in the code shown. `/n` versus `\n` is also a common typo.

Comment: Are you certain that the code in your question is *exactly* the same as the code you compiled and ran? Always copy-and-paste your actual code. It's likely that your problem is that the code you're running isn't the code you showed us -- and that makes it impossible for anyone to give you a definitive answer. (Remember that `'/'` and `'\'` are two different characters, with very different semantics in this context.)

Answer (score 3):

It print `/n` because your program actually contains

```c
printf("hello %s/n", answer);
```

It should be

```c
printf("hello %s\n", answer);
```

And the `$` is your shell prompt.